# Nativescript - upload to appstore UIWebview crash

Tags: nativescript, afnetworking

I´ve been looking for a fix to this but i just can´t seem to find it, i see a lot of people with the same issue but i don´t understand if there is a fix for it right now or not, so i was hopping someone could lead me into the right direction.

The problem is related with this:

> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
>   delivery for your app. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish
>   to correct the following issues in your next delivery:ITMS-90809:
>   Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps
>   that use UIWebView APIs. See
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more
>   information. After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or
>   Application Loader to upload a new binary to App Store Connect. Best
>   regards, The App Store Team

- I´m using [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-https) plugin *(EddyVerbruggen nativescript-https)* and there is an issue opened for this
  matter, it seems it has to do with the **AFNetworking/AFNetworking**
  that is using UIWebView. I alread tried the soluton given by
  **martinprot** but it doesn´t seem to work.
- I´m also using [this](https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager) plugin *(tjvantoll nativescript-IQKeyboardManager)* that has also references to UIWebView.

I found the references by opening my xcworkspace in xcode and searching for UIWebView. I´m using xcode 11.2.1 ; nativescript 6.3.3 ; updated the pods ; start a new project but nothing seems to work, i need the https because apple will not accept POSTS without it.

Could anyone please help me with this one? i´m losing days looking for a solution.

Best regards

Comment: I don't think IQKeyboardManager has references to UIWebView. I use the plugin and have submitted builds even last week without any issues. AFNetworking library still has the issue, did you check this [pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/4439), you might have to take the changes and override the POD in the plugin.

Comment: First, thanks for answering manoj, i´m really lost on this and you are right, the IQKeyboardManager doesnt have references(it´s commented, my bad!)...but in the post you gave me, where exactlly is what i have to do? because i´ve seen that post before and didn´t understand....and by the way, how in you rprojects are you POSTing to a server considering this problem? maybe you do something that i could learn, could you tell me? regards

Comment: You will have to take a fork of the pull request, update Podfile in the plugin - point the source to your forked repo. I think that should help as long there are no breaking changes in the pull request.